# Cancel fax in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, fax

I can't find a way to do this anywhere, not even a mention of it.  But is there is a way to programmatically cancel a fax using, say, a faxserver or faxdocument object?  My current code looks something like this:

```
Set doc=CreateObject("FaxComEx.FaxDocument")
Set server=CreateObject("FaxComEx.FaxServer")
server.Connect ""
doc.Body="c:\somefile.txt"
doc.DocumentName="test fax"
doc.Recipients.Add "1555555555555"
doc.Priority = 1
doc.ConnectedSubmit(server)
```

Using the faxserver.faxserver and faxserver.faxdoc objects doesn't look much more promising, as the only faxdoc method I see is Send.  Is canceling a fax just not possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A related class to `FaxDocument` is [FaxOutgoingJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689115%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) that has a [Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690052%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method.

I've never used it myself but I think that what you have to do is to use the [FaxAccountFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358961%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) object and it's [OutgoingQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa359056%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property which has a [GetJobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa359024%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method.

Comment: That's a pretty good answer, but I'm having problems using the results of the GetJobs method in vbscript, since it only likes variants and not strings.

Comment: @Joe: I wrote an answer to your new question which *might* be helpful.

Comment: Since this solved my problem when I converted to vb6, I'm checking this as the official solution.  Thanks again.